# Rotate a div next to a floated div

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have this layout: (also a [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/shub01/jqtc1671/))

```css
.rotate {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(-10em, 0);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  float: left;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='rotate'>
  Rotated
</div>
<div class='left'>
  Some content....
  <br> Some content....
  <br> Some content....
  <br> Some content....
  <br> Some content....
  <br>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the `.rotate` div to be right next to the `.left` div, however I can't.

I've tried...

- float the rotated div left as well (in the code snippet), but it takes up the width as if it wasn't rotated.
- adding `position:absolute` and `left:0`, but then that overlaps the content

How do I get a div to rotate alongside a left-floated div?

Comment: Isn't it because of your `translate` function? Try `rotate(270deg) translateX(-70px)`. Or I get your question wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `transform-orgin` of the rotated div and also remove the `translate` from that element.

```css
.rotate {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  float:left;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='rotate'>
  Rotated
</div>
<div class='left'>
  Some content....
  <br> Some content....
  <br> Some content....
  <br> Some content....
  <br> Some content....
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems kinda obvious now :P This does bring it together, but it seems the width is still taken up because there's a gap from the left to the rotated content. How would I go about removing that?

Comment: Would you consider translating the rotated image to the left?

Comment: No sorry, it needs to be to the right in this case. Would it be harder to make it work this way?

Comment: just add .rotate { width: 2em;}